# When to choose an older Ubuntu Server version

Tags: 18.04, server, 20.04, versions

What are the differentiating factors between different version numbers? In what circumstances would an older version (for example, 18.04) make more sense as the choice over the most recent version (for example, 20.04).

Conversely, if a newer version of the server comes out, what factors determine when the server should be upgraded to the newer OS?

Comment: Hardware support and new features or packages. If the hardware works well, and you don't need the latest packages, don't upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS has been used by production systems for two years now, so it's seen as more stable. Ubuntu 20.04 LTS has a longer percentage of its supported life left (regardless of count of standard or extended lives). The upgrade path to 20.04 LTS (from 19.10 or 18.04 LTS) hasn't even opened for upgrades yet (unless forced) which shows the '*newness*' of 20.04 LTS.

Other factors such as what packages you want to use, or your needs should of course also be taken into account (20.04 being so new, may not have all wanted programs/3rd party packages made available for it yet). In time, this will of course change.